# Iteration inside function parenthesis

Tags: javascript, function, iteration

This code works as it should.

```
<script>
    function myfunction(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j){
        alert(a);
        alert(b);
        alert(c);
        alert(d);
    }
</script>
<html>
<body>
<p>Hello world</p>
<!-- the arguments in the function are hardcoded -->
<button onclick="javascript: myfunction(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to do something like:

```
<button onclick="javascript: myfunction(iterate 10 times)">Submit</button>
```

Comment: what do you mean with 'iterate 10 times'?

Comment: for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean run the function 10 times, or iterate over each parameter passed to the function where the parameter list is variable?

Comment: -1 please your question isn't very clear, what do you expect in the function arguments? a predicate? an argument list?

Comment: I just wanted to know if it was possible to iterate inside the parenthesis of a function. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Saying the same thing doesn't make it any clearer.

Comment: Please take a look at the answer Cevek gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in js

```
function forFn(from, to){
    var a=[];
    for(var i = from; i <= to; i++){
        a.push(i);
    } 
    return a;
}
```

in html

```
<button onclick="javascript: myfunction.apply(null, forFn(1,10))">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that iterates the arguments time.

`myfunction(5)` will iterate 5 times, `myfunction(10)` will do it 10 times.

```
function myfunction(a){
    for (i = 1; i <= a; i++) { 
        alert(i);
    }
}

myfunction(5);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/L2sp918y/1/

Comment: This will iterate inside the function but not in the function parenthesis.

Comment: This is the answer I was going to give too.  I think you need to improve your question as it's really not clear what you're after.

Comment: Unfortunately it was not the answer I needed then. The user Cevek understood it, so it was clear enough.